# mpi4py fail to receive message

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, mpi4py

I want the master to send data to workers to process and get the result back from the workers. However the code cannot determin. I cannot find the reason, seems the worker fails to receive the data. The code is as follows.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
RANK = comm.Get_rank()
SIZE = comm.Get_size()
def task_master():
    items = list(range(2000))
    results = []
    totalItem = len(items)
    while len(items) > 0:
        status = MPI.Status()
        print('Master before recv %d'%RANK)
        result = comm.recv(status=status)
        print('Master after recv %d'%RANK)
        if result:
            results.append(result)
        rnk = status.Get_source()
        print('Master receive from %d'%rnk)
        print('Master before send %d'%RANK)
        comm.send([items.pop()], dest=rnk)
        print('Master after send %d'%rnk)
        print("Finish: {}/{} {}".format(len(results), totalItem, str(result)))
    for i in range(SIZE):
        comm.send(None, dest=i)

def task_worker():
    while True:
        print('Worker before send %d'%RANK)
        comm.send(1, dest=0)
        print('Worker before recv %d'%RANK)
        data = comm.recv(source=0)
        print("%d Received from 0"%RANK)
        print("%d data:%s"%(RANK, str(data)))
        if not data:
            break
    print("End of %d"%RANK)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_logger(level = logging.INFO)
    if RANK == 0:
        task_master()
    else:
        task_worker()
```

I use python 3.7. open-mpi and mpi4py are all newest version. Just run with `mpiexec -n 10 python`

Comment: How do you observe "fail to receive the data"? One obvious issue in the code is that the master sends the `None` message to itself without posting a receive, so that may deadlock.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong apart from the remark from Zulan. To follow the same rule of worker sends master receives  I would do `for i in range(1,SIZE):
        result = comm.recv(status=status)
        comm.send(None, dest=i)` works allright with my configuration.